# How do I expose ADO Entities via WCF Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, ado.net, datacontract

I linked my database to an Ado Entity Data Model. However when I try to run the a method that exposes all the Members in my model the result is:
            No data received

Is there anyway I can expose the ADO entities without creating a separate DataContract Object for each entity?

Interface

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetAllMembers",
        Method = "GET",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    List<Member> GetAllMembers();
```

Service Class

```
    public List<Member> GetAllMembers()
    {
        using (var context = new DataBaseEntities())
        {
          return context.Members.ToList<Member>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Two things. One, yes you need to explicitly state that the objects are `[DataContract]` to expose them through the service. Two, it is inadvisable to expose ADO.NET entities through a service contract unless this is purely POC or toy code.

Comment: Rather than exposing the ADO.NET entities themselves I made custom objects with just the fields I wanted exposes.